# Can i use immediate property in JSF to refresh my html page without calling any backing bean methods??

Tags: jsf, richfaces, ajax4jsf

Can i use immediate property in JSF to refresh my html page without calling any backing bean methods?? i am new to jsf please suggest & also explain use of immediate

Comment: In which operation you want to refresh the page.

Answer (score 0):

Use `reRender` attribute by using `richfaces` components for refresh the page or particular region of a page.

Comment: i have multiple pages , having multiple dropdown ,input text ,by changing the dropdown value rendering of some of the fields will be changing ,any idea where i can use immediate here?

Comment: use <a4j:support event="onchange" reRender="targetId"></a4j:support> component for refresh the page, and mention the target component id in reRender attribute. You may change the event 'onchange' in a4j support component based on the operations you need to perform.

Comment: <a4j: support> tag is fine but i have been told to find some ways how can i use immediate to reduce backend bean calls & refresh the page faster...any idea??

Answer (score 0):

Imagine that you have this code:

```
<h:form>
    <h:selectOneMenu id="subscriptions"
                     value="#{subscriptionController.subscriptions}" 
                     immediate="true">
        <f:selectItem id="item1" itemLabel="News" itemValue="1" />
        <f:selectItem id="item2" itemLabel="Sports" itemValue="2" />
        <f:selectItem id="item3" itemLabel="Music" itemValue="3" />
        <f:selectItem id="item4" itemLabel="Java" itemValue="4" />
        <f:selectItem id="item5" itemLabel="Web" itemValue="5" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>
</h:form>
```

Regarding the **immediate attribute** is a boolean flag indicating that component events should be sent to registered event listeners immediately rather than after the validation phase of the JSF request processing lifecycle. The immediate flag allows you **bypass** JSF validation for a particular component. [Reference here](http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/help/12-TagReference/html/h_selectOneMenu.html).

JSF life cycle is not easy to understand but you can check a good explanation here: [JSF Life cycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33476/jsf-lifecycle-and-custom-components)

At a next level of experience you can *add* **ajax** to improve **even more** your performance. And the most recommended is to use libraries in that case, for example RichFaces and PrimeFaces.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

According to your requirement it seems that you don't need to use immediate attribute.

Just use f:ajax to process(execute) and update(render) particular elements or group of elements. It will not harm the performance.

And to know JSF Lifecycle and detail of immediate attribute please check [Baluc's Blog](http://balusc.blogspot.in/2006/09/debug-jsf-lifecycle.html#AddImmediateTrueToUIInputOnly)